# Access to LINQ results - what is a better way?

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a set of data from an API call that I need to use. I filter to correct subset and access a specific field with the code below. Is there a better way of getting `currentDate` and `beforeCurrentDate`?

```
DateTime beforeCurrentDate, currDate;

var curr = from c in GlobalResults<FinancialYear>.Results
    where c.IsCurrentYear = true
        select c;

var prev = from c in GlobalResults<FinancialYear>.Results
    where c.ID < curr.FirstOrDefault().ID && c.YearEnd == curr.FirstOrDefault ().YearStart.AddDays(-1)
        select c;


foreach (var cfy in curr)
{
    currDate = cfy.YearEnd;
}

foreach (var pfy in prev)
{
    beforeCurrentDate = pfy.YearStart.AddDays (-1);
}
```

I know the foreach is the wrong way, so what should I use?

EDIT: What the API results contain is a set of dates, with one having the IsCurrent field set to true. I want the EndDate field of the IsCurrent = true result, and the StartDate field of the previous result. Previous ito of the StartDate to EndDate period. The ID field is no use since a previous date range could be captured after the current date range.

Comment: you dont need to do another two foreach loops as you can assign your datetime variables in linq...

Comment: well, if you do nothing else, you should refactor the second query so that it doesn't get the first item from the first query twice.  Eliminate at least one of them.

Comment: What is your desired result? This year and last year??

Comment: I don't think the code is correct. You basically select a random record where IsCurrentYear is true, and then use it in the second query. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: your second query terrifies me: "c.ID < curr.FirstOrDefault().ID" - (why) is this necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var curr = GlobalResults<FinancialYear>.Results.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsCurrentYear);
var prev = GlobalResults<FinancialYear>.Results.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID < curr.ID && c.YearEnd == curr.YearStart.AddDays(-1));

var currDate = curr.YearEnd;
var beforeCurrentDate = prev.YearStart.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Yes. `IEnumerable<T>.Single` is better when there should be only one element that satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current Date for the financial year by constraining the year and choosing the `Last()`, which replaces your `foreach` loop:

```
var currYear = GlobalResults<FinancialYear>.Results.Where(p=>p.IsCurrentYear == true).Last();
var currDate = currYear.YearEnd;
```

Similarly, you can use the `currYear` to get the previous information:

```
var prevYear =  GlobalResults<FinancialYear>.Results.Where(p=>p.YearEnd == currDate.AddDays(-1)).FirstOrDefault();
var beforeCurrentDate = prevYear.YearStart.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Whats the point in selecting the Last? it's as good as any other - the collection is unordered. he could probably use Max instead.